# Why does C use statement as for-loop's condition?

Tags: c, grammar

Like the title says. If I recall correctly, statement shouldn't return any value, then how could C retrieve the value from a statement? (Yes I know compilers can do that, but that would need a little hack, and not beautiful.)

And the increment part of for loop is a expression, which is very confusing too, because you would never need the increment operation's return value.

All my knowledge of C grammar is from [here](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html).

In fact, I'm writing a DSL which tries to follow C's grammar, but it just feels so wrong when implementing the for-loop, especially I decide to make assignment a statement not a expression.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking but the "increment part" of the for-loop can be used to make an assignment; the increment is an implicit assignment itself; no?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils in C, assignment is a expression, which can be used  in the "increment part".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C `for` loop has two grammatical forms and neither of them uses statement as condition

```
for ( expression[opt] ; expression[opt] ; expression[opt] ) statement
for ( declaration expression[opt] ; expression[opt] ) statement
```

At your link someone apparently tried to use `expression_statement` as a replacement for `expression` followed by `;`. That might work grammatically, but it does not reflect the semantics of this language construct. Semantically, the language does not see any "statements" there. The language sees and uses the expression.

> And the increment part of for loop is a expression, which is very confusing too, because you would never need the increment operation's return value.

But that true for [almost] every expression statement in C language. The result of the full expression in expression statement is always discarded. Every time you say

```
printf("Hello World");
```

you discard the result of `printf`. Every time you do

```
a = b + c;
```

you discard the result of the entire expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading your reference material — the [ANSI C Yacc Grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) at Lysator.  It says:

```
iteration_statement
    : WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
    | DO statement WHILE '(' expression ')' ';'
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
    | FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
    ;
```

They are `expression_statements`, not `statements`.  And it makes sense to use expressions in the conditional part of the loop.

```
expression_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'
    ;

statement
    : labeled_statement
    | compound_statement
    | expression_statement
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement
    ;
```

Looking at it, that's a grammar for C90, not C99 or C11 — you can tell from the date as well as the content.  Be aware that C has evolved since that was written.  Not radically, but definitely changed.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I'm not misreading my reference, expression_statement is also a statement, just more specific. And statement don't return values, this is where it cause problems, think of that, you are building a AST node for a for-loop, you will need the conditional part's result to decide whether exit the loop or not, but all you got is a statement node, which will not have a return value in theory, then you either step into that statement node to get the expression, or make expression_statement return values, both are bad practice, I think.

Comment: If you're not misreading it, then you are misunderstanding it.  You can't use any old statement in the context of the `for` loop; you can only use an expression statement, not a labeled statement or a jump statement, etc.  And where a `statement` can be used, any of the alternatives for a `statement` (such as a jump statement) can be used, but that's simply not allowed by the grammar in the control part of a `for` loop.  You can only use expression statements; you cannot use the other types of statement.

Comment: Yes, I know that you can only use expressions there, that is not the problem. The problem is the logic behind the choice of expression_statement rather than expression ';'. But since AnT points out that my reference is not that accurate, I think the our discuss about this is pointless. Thanks for your answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

interesting: however, this kind of statement:

```
FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
```

does not compile.  here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    //FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
    for( a=0; a<10 ) printf( "a=%d\n", a );
    return 0;
}
```

which results in the compiler outputting:

```
  gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes  -c "untitled2.c"  -I.   (in directory: /home/rkwill/Documents/forum)
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:7:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
    for( a=0; a<10 ) printf( "a=%d\n", a );
                ^
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Your initial quote is part of a Yacc grammar.  Since each `expression_statement` explicitly includes a semicolon, that quoted line characterizes a `for` loop such as `for (i = 0; i < 37; )` with no 'increment' in the third section — which is perfectly valid (if marginally unorthodox) C.  The statement after the loop allows for braces or other statements that form the loop body.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  Thanks for the clarification.  As an aside, and and all of the expressions in a `for()` statement are optional.  I just did not know about the 'implicit' in the grammer ';

Comment: And, as an FYI, the grammar in the C90 standard lists `for ( expression_opt ; expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement` as the 'official' grammar (where I've used `_opt` to indicate an 'opt' subscript).  However, the grammar quoted in the question is equivalent to that because of the way it defines `expression`.  C99 and C11 list the notations shown by AnT in his answer.